# Postman - how to use "responseBody.has" with environment variables?

Tags: json, variables, testing, postman

I am trying to achieve the following scenario:

In a GET request I am setting an environment variable with the response of the request using JSON.stringify.

In another GET request I am trying to verify that the created environment variable is present in the JSON response. However this response returns more results than just the one from the previous request.

That is why I need to "search" the response and try to find parts of it that match the ennvironment variable 1:1.

I am trying (for example) with the following tests:

```
var test = postman.getEnvironmentVariable("testvariable")
tests["test1"] = JSON.stringify(responseBody.has(test));
```

This always seems to work, even if I change the contents of the environment variable manually the test still passes. If I remove JSON.stringify then it always fails.

How should I proceed?

Comment: have you tried parsing responseBody and check specific pairs of key value from response.

Comment: Yes, I have. However the elements are shown in a random way and I cannot know which part of the specific JSON array they are going to be. That is why I need to search the whole body.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual) from lodash library
Example:
In your test script you can replace `fromEnv` with your object in Environment variable and `fromBody` with your response string

```
var fromEnv = {"key1": "value1", "key3": "value3", "key2":{"child1":"childValue"}};//environment["envObj"];
var fromBody = {"key2":{"child1":"childValue"}, "key1": "value1", "key3": "value3"};// object from parsed JSON body

tests["objects are equal"] = _.isEqual(fromEnv, fromBody)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get the variable value
var testVar= pm.environment.get("testvariable");

//Validate whether entire response value as a text contains the variable value. 
pm.test("Validate if response contains variable.", function () {
     pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include(testVar);
});
```

Comment: Please take some time to explain what the code means and why your answer answers this particular question.